# CakePHP Console not working with shells

Tags: php, cakephp, console, cakephp-1.3

I have a basic install of cake. I have added the path of the cake console to my profile. However if I run cake bake inside my app directory I get nothing but if I am above my web directory I am able to access the console but obviously none of my shells.

EG

```
/mnt/dev/app # cake (returns me to new prompt)

/mnt # cake (gives me the console)
```

My path is set as:
`PATH='/mnt/dev/cake/console':$PATH`

Stuck!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
cd /mnt/dev
cake/console/cake bake all
```

Have you set up your database correctly?

Comment: That just returns me to the prompt - database is configured correctly. App works, just not console/shells

Answer (score 0):

Maybe typing `which cake` at both these locations will give you more info.

In my projects, i have a file in de app root called `cake` with something like this in it:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/cakephp-1.2.8/cake/console/cake "$@"
```

This will allow you to use `./cake` from the app root. The reason i use this is because i need different versions of cake for each project.